# How to write controller for long running batch?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have cron job in spring boot api which starts a batch. The batch takes around 30 mins to complete. I am not sure how should i write controller for this. I want to add one sos plan so that if the batch misses some data or it does run due to any reason i can call one end point and start that batch.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no straightforward solution for your problem and it should be based on your particular requirements and application flow.

Meanwhile, a common approach would be to implement two endpoints, one for triggering your batch job, and another one for monitoring its progress / failure...

There is no *Spring Batch* afforded API for querying the batch job status and to trigger parametrizable executions, but you can either use or get inspired by the [Spring Batch Rest](https://github.com/chrisgleissner/spring-batch-rest) OSS project.

Comment: no i am not using spring batch. I calling this end point which in turns calls this method of batch execution. All i want is to start this batch. Thats it.

Comment: @NoobCoder `no i am not using spring batch`: in this case, why are you tagging your question with `spring-batch`? I will remove that tag.